# django tables2 display sort arrows on header (follow-on question)

Tags: django-tables2

Building off the question and answer in [this prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65701753/how-to-format-django-filters-using-crispy-forms), what django-tables2 puts out comes out as:  [example table where heading text is the link and the arrows are not active.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKFEy.png)  When I create the table, my template uses `{% render_table table %}`

The example in the twitter blog has a better UX because the entire table header cell is the link.  How do I do that with django-tables2?

Thanks

Following up with some experimentation, I've been able to make table `<td>` cells work `<a href="">label</a>` via bootstrap, django-tables2 meta attrs, and `render_col()`.  However, I cannot get the `<th>` to work.  The `th` definition sets the container fine, but I cannot get the subtending `<a>` that django-tables2 generates to include reference to the bootstrap class.  I can't find a render() for table headers.

Here's my code:

```
attrs = {"class": "table table-striped table-sm ",
                 "th": {"class": "col-md-2 position-relative",
                        "a": {"class": "stretched-link"},
                        },
                 "td": {"class": "col-md-2 position-relative"},
                 }
```

and here's what gets generated:

```
<th class="asc col-md-2 orderable position-relative" a="{'class': 'stretched-link'}">
   <a href="?sort=-first_name">First name</a>
</th>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it this way after some experimentation and search.  Turns out the key is a bootstrap utility (stretch-link) and putting this class on the link rather than the th elements.  Open to better solutions.

```
class StudentTable(tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "nickname", "status")
        sequence = ("last_name", "first_name", "nickname", 'status')
        attrs = {"class": "table table-striped table-sm "}

    def make_string(self, value, record):
        temp = reverse('client:student_information', kwargs={'pk': record.id})
        the_str = f"<a href='{temp}' class='url-no-underline stretched-link'> {value} </a>"
        return the_str

    def render_first_name(self, value, record):
        return mark_safe(self.make_string(value, record))
```